# avoid springboot duplicate log logback

Tags: spring-mvc, logback

.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
 \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.3.RELEASE)

2017-05-09 22:31:48.424  INFO 10820 --- [  restartedMain] com.bearmom.app.AppServiceApplication    : Starting AppServiceApplication on TheKing with PID 10820 (F:\bearmon-app-service\target\classes started by King in E:\workspace_idea\code)
[2017-05-09 22:31:48.424]  INFO  com.bearmom.app.AppServiceApplication - Starting AppServiceApplication on TheKing with PID 10820 (F:\bearmon-app-service\target\classes started by King in E:\workspace_idea\code)
2017-05-09 22:31:48.443  INFO 10820 --- [  restartedMain] com.bearmom.app.AppServiceApplication    : The following profiles are active: dev
[2017-05-09 22:31:48.443]  INFO  com.bearmom.app.AppServiceApplication - The following profiles are active: dev
2017-05-09 22:31:53.297  INFO 10820 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@598b4233: startup date [Tue May 09 22:31:53 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[2017-05-09 22:31:53.297]  INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@598b4233: startup date [Tue May 09 22:31:53 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-09 22:31:59.576  INFO 10820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-context-web.xml]
[2017-05-09 22:31:59.576]  INFO  o.s.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-context-web.xml]
2017-05-09 22:32:00.524  INFO 10820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-mybatis.xml]
[2017-05-09 22:32:00.524]  INFO  o.s.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-mybatis.xml]
2017-05-09 22:32:00.776  INFO 10820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-redis.xml]
[2017-05-09 22:32:00.776]  INFO  o.s.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-redis.xml]
2017-05-09 22:32:00.834  INFO 10820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-oss.xml]
[2017-05-09 22:32:00.834]  INFO  o.s.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-oss.xml]
2017-05-09 22:32:01.544  WARN 10820 --- [  restartedMain] o.m.s.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner      : No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.bearmom.app]' package. Please check your configuration.
[2017-05-09 22:32:01.544]  WARN  org.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner - No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.bearmom.app]' package. Please check your configuration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is this lol

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AFKb.pngenter code here